# Dispatch срабатывает дважды. Не понимаю почему

Tags: reactjs, redux

Сразу извиняюсь за плохо сформулированный вопрос, не знаю, как его правильно построить.

Прилагаю код контейнерной компоненты, редьюсера и презентационной компоненты.

Я сетаю 3 объекта в массив только если его длина равна 0. Но почему-то при этом условии срабатывает дважды.

Сверялся с видео уроком, там только 3 записи, у меня 6(должно быть 3, но есть повторение)

**Users.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import avatar from "../../assets/img/avatar.png";
import styles from "./users.module.css";
import axios from "axios";

class Users extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://social-network.samuraijs.com/api/1.0/users')
            .then(response => this.props.setUsers(response.data.items))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={styles.users}>
                {
                    this.props.users.map(user =>
                        <div className={styles.inner}>
                            <div className={styles.user}>
                                <img src={user.photos.small ? user.photos.small : avatar} alt="avatar" width={60} height={60}/>
                                {
                                    user.followed ? 
                                        <button className={styles.following} onClick={() => this.props.unfollow(user.id)}>Отписаться</button> : 
                                        <button className={styles.following} onClick={() => this.props.follow(user.id)}>Подписаться</button>
                                }
                            </div>
    
                            <div className={styles.info}>
                                <div className={styles.about}>
                                    <h3 className={styles.name}>
                                        {user.name}
                                    </h3>
                                    <p className={styles.status}>
                                        {user.status}
                                    </p>
                                </div>
    
                                <div className={styles.location}>
                                    <p className={styles.city}>
                                        Vladivostok
                                    </p>
                                    <p className={styles.country}>
                                        Russia
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Users;
```

**usersReducer.js**

```
const FOLLOW = 'FOLLOW';
const UNFOLLOW = 'UNFOLLOW';
const SET_USERS = 'SET_USERS';

const initialState = {
    users: []
}

const usersReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case FOLLOW: {
            return {
                ...state,
                users: state.users.map(user => {
                    if (user.id === action.userId){
                        return {...user, followed: true};
                    }
                    return user;
                })
            }
        }

        case UNFOLLOW: {
            return {
                ...state,
                users: state.users.map(user => {
                    if (user.id === action.userId){
                        return {...user, followed: false};
                    }
                    return user;
                })
            }
        }

        case SET_USERS: {
            return {
                ...state,
                users: [...state.users, ...action.users]
            }
        }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const followCreator = (userId) => ({type: FOLLOW, userId});
export const unfollowCreator = (userId) => ({type: UNFOLLOW, userId});
export const setUsersCreator = (users) => ({type: SET_USERS, users});

export default usersReducer;
```

**UsersContainer.js**

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { followCreator, setUsersCreator, unfollowCreator } from "../../redux/usersReducer";
import Users from "./Users";

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        users: state.USERS_PAGE.users
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        follow: (userId) => {
            dispatch(followCreator(userId));
        },
        unfollow: (userId) => {
            dispatch(unfollowCreator(userId));
        },
        setUsers: (users) => {
            dispatch(setUsersCreator(users));
        }
    }
}

const UsersContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Users);

export default UsersContainer;
```

Comment: пиши на redux toolkit, будет проще

Comment: Если у вас 18 реакт, то в режиме дев разработки он ставит компоненты дважды в строгом режиме. Уберите if из тела функции и положите в хук состояния или эффекта

Comment: А почему так, не подскажете?

Comment: Изменение состояния в redux и react это асинхронные операции. Установка компонентов осуществляется дважды без ожидания завершения всех остальных вызовов. Как результат, видим задвоение, т.к. дважды в redux улетают данные. Вам надо изменить логику добавления данных в redux, что бы это не зависело от рендера компоента(**Рекомендую**), либо убрать двойной рендер. [Как убрать двойной рендер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1473214/)

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что раннее это работало иначе?

Comment: В классовой компоненте тоже почему-то два раза данные добавляются, хотя они прописаны в конструкторе, он же по идее только один раз вызывается

Comment: Даже если в ComponentDidMount прописать, почему-то дублируется